# Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start method explanation

Tags: c#, windows-8

This code is from **Programming Windows, Sixth Edition** book:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation; 
using Windows.UI; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls; 
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;    

namespace StrippedDownHello
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Start((p) => new App());
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

I cannot understand the syntax of `Application.Start((p) => new App());` line. In the class documentation `Start` method is defined as:

```
public static void Start(ApplicationInitializationCallback callback);
```

Please explain me how this code line with lambda expression is related to the `Start` method definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda is just shortcut to write an instance of the [ApplicationInitializationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.applicationinitializationcallback)

You can check the signature of this delegate and see that it indeed takes a parameter and return nothing.

In your example, the lambda is doing exactly this: takes a parameter p, instantiates an App and return nothing.

Without using lambda you would write it like this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Start(new ApplicationInitializationCallback(Start));
        }

        private static void Start(ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams p)
        {
            new App();
        }
```